# Unbounded continuous function, on a set with a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Say $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and we suppose there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ converging to a number $x_0 \in S$. Is there an unbounded continuous function on $S$?

(real analysis, from Ken Ross' book Elementary Analysis)

My instinct tells me no, that a convergent sequence hints at some discontinuity, but I'm not sure. I want to apply the Bolzano-Weierstross Theorem, I think.

Comment: Is this really the problem statement?  As it stands the answer is "maybe, maybe not".  There are some $S$ satisfying this condition that do have unbounded continuous functions, and others that do not.  (For example $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ both have the property.  If you allow constant sequences then every nonempty set has the property.)

Comment: Unbounded on $S$ or unbounded on the set $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$?

Comment: I think he means that $S = \{x_n \in \mathbb{N \cup \{0\}}\}$

Comment: Funny, an answer is accepted while it has been explicitely signalled that the question is unclear and no answer to these queries from the OP was deemed useful.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear $S$ only contains the sequence. It's the only way the question isn't nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $f(x_0) = L$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta$ so that for all $x_n \in S$ such that $|x - x_n| < \delta$ we have $|f(x_0)-f(x_n)| < \epsilon $. This includes all but finitely many of the $x_n$. Thus $|f| < L + \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ for some $N$. So $|f(x_n)| \leq max(L + \epsilon, |f(x_1)|,...,|f(x_N)|)$ for all $n$.

Comment: $S$ only contains the sequence..